# Segmentation fault when copy chars from char[] to char**

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I encounter a strange error when I try to copy one char at a time from a big char[] to a char**. I need to split a text into chunks of 16 and store them in an array, my thought was that I have to take the text size and get the number of chunks. When I try to copy chunks of 16 in each line of the array at the end I get Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault.
As a sample text here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char simpleText[] = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    int size = strlen(simpleText);
    int chunks = size / 16;
    int r = size % 16;
    char** screen = (char**) malloc(chunks * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
        screen[i] = (char*) malloc (16 * sizeof(char));
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int row = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char c = simpleText[i];
        screen [row][counter] = c;
        counter++;

        if (counter == 16 || i == size) {
            screen[row][counter] = '\0';
            counter = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }
    printf("=========================================================\n");
}
```

The code fails when row is 35 at this line:  `screen [row][counter] = c;`. I searched around but I can't seem to understand why it fails.

Comment: `int chunks = size / 16;` That's going to give you one chunk less than required unless the `size` is an exact multiple of 16. Need to add 1 in the case that `r` is not 0.

Comment: OK, so I need to do something like this? size = ((size % 16 )== 0) ? size / 16: (size/16) + 16;

Comment: Example: `if (r != 0) chunks++;` Don't change the `size` as that needs to remain exactly the length of the input string.

Comment: Oh, now I get it, thank you!

Comment: and now you write 1 character beyond the allocated buffers

Comment: As @rioV8 said.  0-15 is 16 chars, but you are adding a '\0' at index 16 which is the 17th char.

Answer (score 0):

Each char array in `screen` has memory allocated for 16 chars.

```
screen[i] = (char*) malloc (16 * sizeof(char));
```

However, in the following, you've accessed the *17th* char in each of those char arrays. Remember that C arrays are indexed starting at `0`, so the last index for a 16 element array is *`15`*, and because a C string is null-terminated, a char array of length 16 can hold a string with 15 characters.

```
        if (counter == 16 || i == size) {
            screen[row][counter] = '\0';
            counter = 0;
            row++;
        }
```